# Prolog instantiation error?

Tags: prolog

I'm stuck with some sort of error which i don't really understand in Prolog. I get this error when calling a rule(which seems to work sometimes?) :

`error(instantiation_error,Var0)`

Can anyone explain to me what this means?

so i have two rules:

`special(X) :- user(X, Days), Days >= 20.`

`special(X) :- premiumuser(X).`

`user(guy, 40).`

although user is added dynamically sometimes it is not in the Prolog db. I can eliminate the first special(x) rule and the error goes.

when call call:

`special(someone).`

I get the error

Comment: Can you eliminate either of the rules and still reproduce the error? what about the facts/rules for user/2?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with your code in SWI-Prolog, assuming `premiumuser/1` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have applied a functor which only works with atoms (e.g., `<`) to an uninstantiated variable. You need to post minimal code that demonstrates the problem before we can tell you any more.